# Can't get beautifulsoup4 installed on Mac OSX Catalina

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

I have tried several different ways to install beautifulsoup4 and I always get the following:

> Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable

- tried pip3 install beautifulsoup4
- tried sudo pip3 install beautifulsoup4
- tired python3 -m pip install beautifulsoup4

None of these options work.  They all basically say that it is installed for python2 and won't work for python3.

I need some guidance. I am running MacOS Catalina.

Comment: Can you post the error you're getting?

Comment: I got it fixed! I had an old package of bs4 in my project library that was messing it up!